# How to separate the output of information for each memory bar? And how to remove information about empty slots in the output?

Tags: linux, bash

I wrote the following command

```
dmidecode -t memory | awk '/\tFactor/{i++;print "Memory  "i"}/\tSpeed|GB|\tFactor/'
```

The information is displayed as follows:

```
Speed: 3200 MT/s
    Volatile Size: 32 GB
    Speed: Unknown
    Speed: Unknown
    Speed: Unknown
    Size: 32 GB
    Speed: 3200 MT/s
    Volatile Size: 32 GB
    Speed: Unknown
    Speed: Unknown
    Speed: Unknown
    Speed: Unknown
    Size: 32 GB
    Speed: 3200 MT/s
    Volatile Size: 32 GB
    Speed: Unknown
    Speed: Unknown
    Speed: Unknown
    Size: 32 GB
    Speed: 3200 MT/s
    Volatile Size: 32 GB
    Speed: Unknown
    Speed: Unknown
```

How can I make the output look like this:

```
Memory1
       Speed
       The size
       Volatile Size
Memory2
```

And what would take all the information where there is no data and the value is "Unknown" ??

Comment: please update the question to show 3 distinct sets of data ... the output from `dmidecode -t memory` ... the (wrong?) output from your current code (`dmidecode -t memory | awk ...`) ... the (correct) expected output

Comment: On the motherboard you have memory slots; `dmidecode` will provide the info about each one of those slots; when there's no RAM module plugged in in the slot, then you'll get a `Speed: Unknown` or whatever.

Comment: Your `awk` command has a syntax issue.  `print "Memory  "i"` should be `print "Memory  i"`

Comment: @Fravadona How i сan remove unknown memory ports from the output? The "for" loop didn't work.

Comment: @Nic3500 How i сan remove unknown memory ports from the output?

Comment: @markp-fuso  How i сan remove unknown memory ports from the output? The "for" loop didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I did this:

```
sudo dmidecode -t memory | awk -f dmidecoce.awk
```

---

File **dmidecode.awk**

```
/Memory Device/ {
    i++
    print "Memory" i
}
/^\tSpeed:/
/^\tSize:/
/^\tVolatile Size:/
```

For others that might read this answer, for `/^\tSpeed:/`, there is no action (no code between `{ }` following the pattern), so `awk` simply prints the matching line.

---

Result:

```
Memory1
    Size: 8192 MB
    Speed: 1600 MT/s
Memory2
    Size: 8192 MB
    Speed: 1600 MT/s
Memory3
    Size: 8192 MB
    Speed: 1600 MT/s
Memory4
    Size: 8192 MB
    Speed: 1600 MT/s
```

---

On my laptop, I did not see anything in the `dmidecode` output that matches *volatile size* you want.  Adjust according do your specific hardware and `dmidecode` output.

---

**EDIT**

If you have "unknown" lines that you want to remove, you can do this:

```
/^\tSpeed:/ && !/Unknown/
```

This will capture the "Speed" lines, except those that contain "Unknown".